# Trying to create custom vim functions

Tags: vim

This is my ~/.vimrc

```
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
syntax enable

""" <F5> calls make
function! CallMake() 
    :!make
endfunction
:map <F5> :call CallMake()<CR>
:imap <F5> <C-O>:call CallMake()<CR>

""" <F6> calls run.sh
function! CallRun()
    :!./run.sh
endfunction
:map <F6> :call CallRun()<CR>
:imap <F6> <C-O>:call CallRun()<CR>

""" Test
map <F7> :ls<CR>
map! <F7> :ls<CR>

""" Remapped keys
" swap ; and : in normal mode
nnoremap ; :
nnoremap : ;

" exit insert mode with jk
imap jk <Esc>

" show commands as you're typing them
set showcmd

" enable mouse
set mouse=a

" show line numbers
set number

""" Search options
set hlsearch
set ignorecase

""" tabs
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab

colors koehler
```

The problem is all I get when I press F5, F6, or F7 is the terminal bell. 
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using the default Ubuntu 10.10 terminal, and zsh as my shell, if either of those matter.

The goal here is to make F5 to call make in the current directory, and make F6 call 
./run.sh in the current directory. If there is a better way than how I'm doing it,
I'd also like to know about that.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here might be with your terminal.
To test that try the following:
where you map `<f5>`, intead of

```
map <F5> :call CallMake()<CR>
```

type

```
map ctrl-v<F5> :call CallMake()<CR>
```

where `ctrl-v<F5>` means explicitly typing ctrl-v followed by the key `F5`.

If after this the `F5` mapping work it means you have your terminal wrongly configured.

Comment: This works! when I type "ctrl-v" followed by F5, my function gets called. If anyone know where to start configuring the terminal, please let me know.

Comment: which system and what terminal are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.10 with the default terminal

Comment: what does "printenv TERM" gives you?

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work then. It works fine for me. Does the same happen with other terminals like konsole or xterm?